# Safari not displaying text when using character

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

When I use an ampersand symbol or any symbol in my code it will display correctly on every browser except Safari. On Safari the symbol will show but not the content of the class. (the numbers). Once I remove the symbol the content will display correctly on Safari.

```
<h4 class="classname">12345 &amp; 678910</h4>
```

CSS code

```
  .classname {

        background:url(../images/pic.png) 0 32px no-repeat;
        float:right;
        padding:19px 25px 0 30px;
```

Comment: I don;t think that it's the code you've posted that's causing the problem for you. I take it there is lots more code round about this? Can you post that too or a link to your webpage where the problem is happening?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Link to full code. http://jsfiddle.net/bjPaz/

Comment: @user1016078. Your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjPaz/) works fine on my iPhone 4s (iOS 5.1.1) Safari browser.

Comment: That's displaying the ampersand fine in Safari for me too I'm afraid.

Comment: I found the problem. For some reason (bad code) using the ampersand was causing the text in the class to use the background color hence why I couldn't see the number. Thanks Billy and flem for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me in Safari 5.1.1: 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPz6W/).
[image: Safari Fiddle]

I can't provide a screenshot but it also works fine on Safari for iPhone4 (iOS 5.1.1).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I should have said. It's Safari on the iPad and iPhone that it isn't working on.

Comment: My code must be messed up because it works find on a test file.

Comment: @user1016078. Absolutely. It works fine on Safari on my iPhone4. If you can't source the problem, add more and more of your code to the fiddle until it breaks, then edit your question with the fiddle included.